# c#.net if textbox1.text is not null and is > 8

Tags: null

Visual Studio 2015 community
Windows Desktop Forms
C#

I have looked all over but can't find a solution to this one.

i need to check if a text box has text AND is at least 8 Characters.

if textbox1.text is not null and is > 8

Any Help would be AWESOME.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  What isn't working?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a string is null or empty:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)
```

(I recommend this instead of just checking for null, as a UI input might always be represented as an empty string and never as null.)

And you can check the length of a string:

```
textBox1.Text.Length >= 8
```

Using these, you can build your condition:

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) &&
    (textBox1.Text.Length >= 8))
```

(I may be a little overzealous with the parentheses on that, but I like to be explicit in code.)

Comment: PERFECT, Thank you David. Its nice to get a straight answer with out being bashed for a 45 year old Newbie to c#. I'm and old Delphi Programmer. this is going to be a heck of a CURVE. Thanks again.